# How to put a block below text

Tags: html, css

I have tried to find how to put a block of color below the text and ontop of the background image so that the text does not blend in with background image. I have not be able to find out how to do it. any help is greatly sppreciated.

here is style.css

```
body {
    background-image: url("beach.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

p { color:#000000;line-height:2em;}
p.margin {
    text-align: justify;
}

#banner {position:relative, margin:auto auto;}
#header{background-color: #fff; width: 1000px; position: relative; }
#bannerL {position:relative, margin:auto auto;}
#bannerR {
    position: relative; 
    float: right; 
}

h1 { text-align: center}
h1 {font-size:50px}
```

Comment: Greetings .. you are invited to take the tour of http://stackoverflow.com/tour. It is filled with all you need to know about 'how' to ask a question. User Indian is right, what have you tried so far?  Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist. In the meantime, put your question on **[HOLD]** to avoid beeing downvoted while you edit your post.

Comment: I havent tried anything, i have spent hours trying to find even one thing to try, and to no avial. I have not found anything even answering my question. i don't know correct terms that is part of my problem. I bought a html book, but it is helping little

Comment: @user3089861: you should try something. here no one will write code for you..

Comment: I know, I am not trying to have that. That is why after looking on internet and w3 and still not found anything I came here. I did try to solve it myself. I even bought a book. I apologize for bothering you all.

Comment: I know little, and instead of helping me or telling me where I can learn you tell me to go try things. what do i try if i know little code. This is why i came here to get help, not to get told to continue looking for answers that are not there

Comment: If you showed your HTML code and an image of the desired appearance (well, link to an online image), people could at least see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: okay, thank you for help, that is a good idea. I will try that next time. I do not wish to offend other users here.

Comment: @user3089861 : www.homeandlearn.co.uk, www.tutorialspoint.com. you should practice in your home. write some code (it is right or not thats not a problem). if u get any error or if u didn't get the result what you want post that code here. many programmers are here. they will help you.. practice makes a man perfect.. try try something..

Comment: wow, thanks man. I will make sure to try a few things before I post a question next time. Thanks for the sites too!

Comment: @user3089861 : www.w3schools.com, www.css-tricks.com... all the best. me too learning.. just a beginner..:)

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns: the questioner can't put a question on hold by themselves, and they still can be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a `background-color` attribute to `p`, like this :

```
p {
    background-color: rgba(125, 0, 100, 0.7);
}
```

Or you can put all your text into a `div`, like this:

```
<div class="content">
    All my content
</div>
```

And in your css:

```
.content {
    background-color: rgba(125, 13, 42, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want the background-color to follow the text lines you switch the p tag to a span tag instead, which is displayed inline.